# Java NetBeans Beginner: Import Filesystem

Tags: java, filesystems, netbeans-6.9

I am new to Netbeans (using 6.9.1) and want to ask the following:
Is there an import Project or import filesystem in NetBeans the same way as there is in Eclipse?
I have a project in NetBeans and I want to make some temporary changes to see if they work.
I thought that I could do it by creating a new project and then import filesystem so that I have 2 projects with the same code, but one of them would be a throw-away (just to see if some changes in code work). I can not find an import filesystem in netbeans. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just duplicating the directory folder for the project should do it, then open the duplicated project as usual i NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

In the projects windows, you can right click on the project which you want to duplicate and select "copy". Then you will be asked for the destination path. You can delete a project the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Usually copying the files under the /src folder from your original project and paste them in the /src of the target folder does the trick. If you used any resources, such as .jar files in the source project you will obviously have to import them back again in the target project in the same manner. 
You might also have to restart the IDE so that the changes you made to the file system are reflected in the IDE itself.